# Java EE 7 CDI - Injection doesn't work, sending NullPointerException

Tags: vaadin, cdi, java-ee-7, wildfly

I have a problem with my injection, it's the first time I try it. I'm working with Wildfly and Java EE 7. I've got a `NullPointerException` when trying to access `Authenticator` instance in `LoginController`.

I use maven, my beans.xml is found under `src/main/webapp/META-INF` but I'v tried to put it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` without success.

Here is my code :

The class to inject :

```
@Stateless
public class Authenticator {

    @Inject
    HashGenerator hashGenerator;

    @Inject
    UserPersistance userPersistance;

    public boolean authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
        User user = userPersistance.getUser(username);
        String salt = user.getSalt();
        String hash = hashGenerator.hash(password, salt);
        return user.getPassword().equals(hash);
    }
}
```

The controller which throw NullPointerException :

```
@Stateless
public class LoginController {

    @Inject
    Authenticator authenticator;

    public void login(String username, String password) {
        if (authenticator.authenticate(username, password)) {
            UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
            ui.getSession().setAttribute(SessionAttribute.USER.getAttributeName(), username);
            ui.getNavigator().navigateTo(MainView.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And my beans.xml (Under `src/main/webapp/META-INF`)

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

What did I do wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I previously miswritten the folders name of beans.xml.

So, just to be clear, maven generate a WAR archive, and I've previously tried to put beans.xml under `META-INF` , `WEB-INF` and `WEB-INF/classes`. None of those folder seems to make it work. I've checked (tried and it works) a quickstart project from JBoss AS 7, and they put beans.xml under `WEB-INF`. I've done the same.

I think that maybe it comes from my Maven configuration. Here it is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.normegil</groupId>
    <artifactId>datamanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>datamanager</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>        
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <vaadin.version>7.1.9</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: For a web application, the beans.xml deployment descriptor,must be in the WEB-INF directory. For EJB modules or JAR files, the beans.xml deployment descriptor, must be in the META-INF directory

Comment: Wildfly's CDI does auto-discovery, so beans.xml shouldn't be necessary at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I was able to fix my problem, here is what I've done :

**Maven dependencies**

I was assuming that `javax:javaee-api` was enough to use the functionnalities of Java EE 7. I've added dependencies to `javax.enterprise:cdi-api`, `javax.inject:javax.inject` and `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api`

**beans.xml**

It's only one big project build into a war archive. I've put my beans.xml under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` (Is it necessary to have it at all with Wildfly ? Don't know)

**Vaadin CDIUI**

That's what solved my issue. I've tried to use Vaadin CDIUI without success. Vaadin was actually initializing my UI class with a `new` operation. Since it was not managed by the container, every Injection points didn't work (I've first fix it by doing `new` operations on my views and controllers, falling on the problem I've described)

I've refactored everything so injection is used in the views and controllers, and I've added `@CDIUI` to my Vaadin UI. Last, I've also added a new parameter to my servlet configuration (`UIProvider`) for this result :

```
@Theme("chameleon-green")
@Title("Data Manager")
@CDIUI("")
public class DataManagerUI extends UI {
    @WebServlet(value = "/*",
            asyncSupported = true,
            initParams = {@WebInitParam(
                    name = "session-timeout",
                    value = "60"
            ),@WebInitParam(
                    name = "UIProvider",
                    value = "com.vaadin.cdi.CDIUIProvider"
            )}
    )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false,
            ui = DataManagerUI.class,
            closeIdleSessions = true
    )
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    [...]
}
```

When normally instantiated with `new` operation from Vaadin framework, the UI class should be given by the `UIProvider` when using Injection.

Thanks for the help !