# @Inject @ThirteenNumber throw NullPointException

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, inject

I try to work with `@Injection`, so start with a simple example here :

**Interface**

```
public interface NumberGenerator {
    String generateNumber();
}
```

**BookService**

```
public class BookServices {

    @Inject
    @ThirteenNumber
    private NumberGenerator generator;

    public Book createBook(String title){
        return new Book(title, generator.generateNumber());
    }
}
```

**Book Object**

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String isbn;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title, String isbn) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**CDI**

```
@Named(value = "injectionTest") 
@ViewScoped 
public class InjectionTest implements Serializable {

    public void showResult() {
        BookServices bookService = new BookServices();
        Book book = bookService.createBook("Java book");
        System.out.println(book.toString());
    }

    //...
}
```

**ThirteenNumber Implementation**

```
@ThirteenNumber
public class IsbnGenerator implements NumberGenerator{

    @Override
    public String generateNumber(){
        return "13-84333-" + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When i try to call `bookService.createBook("Java book")` it throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, in `generator.generateNumber()` i think it not call the right `@Qualifier`, a tried to solve this problem, using this link, [Java EE 7 CDI - Injection doesn't work, sending NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363931/java-ee-7-cdi-injection-doesnt-work-sending-nullpointerexception) i add all the dependencies but the problem still the same?

Did i miss something?

**Note** i know about [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the `new BookServices()` in your InjectionTest class. The `new` operator breaks CDI. Just `@Inject` the `BookServices`

Comment: thank you @Rouliboy this is really was helpful, i get another error after that `CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type BookServices with qualifiers @Default` i solved it like this 1- implements Serializable in BookServices and change `bean-discovery-mode` to `bean-discovery-mode="all"` thank you so much again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `new BookServices()` in your `InjectionTest` class. The `new` operator breaks CDI. Just `@Inject` the `BookServices` bean.